# .net web service call with callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Does anyone know how to send a "callback" parameter of sorts to a web service, so that, when a certain action is completed, the web service can invoke the callback, without return a value from the action.

For example, a progress percentage, or more similar to my problem:

- you have 3 fruits ( apples, oranges and lemons )
- you ask information about all the fruits ( the 3 fruits )

I want the web service to return each value as soon as it knows the answer to each fruit, but also, remains in the same action call, so I don`t have the problem of logging a ton of different calls ( in reality, there are more than 3 fruits ), as the clients interact with certain aspect of the logging, and it can be very confusing

```
 static void ClientFunction()
    {
        WebServiceFunction(Letters.All);
    }
    static bool WebServiceFunction(Letters whatLetters)
    {

        bool checkA = whatLetters == Letters.A, checkB = whatLetters == Letters.B, checkC = whatLetters = Letters.C,
            checkAll = whatLetters == Letters.All;

        //async wrapped
        if(checkA || checkAll)
        {
            // do something A
            // and send the answer to the client as soon as it is known
        }

        //async wrapped
        if (checkB || checkAll)
        {
            // do something B
            // and send the answer to the client as soon as it is known
        }

        //async wrapped
        if (checkC || checkAll)
        {
            // find out something about c
            // and send the answer to the client as soon as it is known
        }



        // lets say this is a generic return value ( for whatever the service does)
        return true;

    }

    enum Letters
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        All
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the webservice should execute the callback serverside or the it sould let the caller know that he can now execute the callback. also do you already have some code?

Comment: I just edited the question with some example code

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WCF duplex stuff

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problems is that the web service is already configured and used by various parties. So changing the type of service is out of the question ( and so is a new solution )